# Cloud Backup General Purpose

Tags: cloud

I wish to back up directories to a web cloud in a simple way: Using either Terminal or Gnome clicking, I delete older versions from the cloud. I select directories I want to back up and send them to the cloud. I want a simple and of course secure service; it can be free or paid. What is a good website for this? What utility is required?

Answer (score 0):

This question was too simple for sophisticated users, so I will mention a solution I stumbled on. If one has a Google account (which is free), there is 15GB of storage available already, which can be mounted as a drive (like a USB stick, say) using Gnome. The method is at: 
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-google-drive-linux-4176144.
There are many elaborations for this service, but this is a start.